# Linux SED AWK Sqlite dump to MySQL change string to varchar on lines that start with create table

Tags: mysql, bash, sqlite, sed, awk

I need an inline sed command to replace "string" with "varchar(30)" however the create table syntax can be on multiple lines.

Is there a way to tell sed (or with awk?) to make that substitution on lines that don't start with "INSERT INTO..." ?

the word "string" may appear in my data and I don't want the data corrupted.

```
sed -i 's/string/varchar(30)/g'
```

I know basic regex but this is beyond me. Thanks!

Comment: even you have accepted the answer, I still recommend to show us some sample input files that others can understand your question easily.

Comment: I actually finally gave up trying to convert sqlite .dump to mysql syntax. I'm now converted sqlite to csv and csv to mysql. No SED or AWK needed. I can show the code for that if any one is interested but I think it's more relevant at the #1 thread on google about that topic. I can append it there as an alternative method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i '/^INSERT INTO/! s/string/varchar(30)/g'
```

From the [sed man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

> After the address (or address-range), and before the command, a **`!`**  may be inserted, which specifies that the command shall  only  be  executed if the address (or address-range) does **not** match.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of labels.

Using gnu sed:

```
sed -i '/^INSERT INTO/b a; s/string/varchar(30)/g; :a' filename
```

otherwise

```
sed -i -e '/^INSERT INTO/b a' -e 's/string/varchar(30)/g' -e :a filename
```

Comment: can you explain what the /b is for?

Comment: `a` is a label; `b a` implies branch to label `a`; it branches if the match is successful.